# how to fix port number for any request?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have to implement the logic of `multicasting` on my system itself,,
so at system level I thought to make a groups of `port number` would be good.

the goal is to implement `tcp multicasting` in `java socket programming`.

so that I would define the `groups` `statically` in `hashMap` by group id's, and each group contains a set of port numbers in order to multicast the message.(tell me if it is possible in tcp because I found MultiSocket class for UDP multicasting in Java).

for an instance my server is `listening` to `port no.` `5555` ,,and I want to connect to a client by
`$ telnet localhost 5555` , and this client would make a request through a `port number`(let it be `42223`) given by `kernel`(can be known by `conn.getPort()` in the server side where `conn` is a `client socket object)`,,

So my question is - Can I fix the `42223` part here?? If not then please suggest how can I implement multicast on same system? my system is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: "Can I fix the 42223 part here" - why do you consider it broken? That's how TCP works. Clients connect to a Server port and are given a client port. You can handle several clients and spread messages among them. But "true" multicast like possible in UDP ... not 100% sure (but pretty close) I think is impossible.

Comment: Thanx,@Fildor ,well it means I cant make multicast in tcp??

Comment: As far as I know. Because tcp is designed to have two "ends" of communication.